# jQuery.Mobile autodivider listview linkbar not working in div section with max-height set

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am using jquery mobile with autodivider active. The linkbar (alphascroll) from this website: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/examples/listviews/autodividers-linkbar.html#&ui-state=dialog works pretty well when I allow the list of information on my page to continue on with out any restriction on size on the page. This creates a scroll bar on the entire page and then clicking on a letter scrolls the entire page to the correct location. However, that will not work for my website. My design has the scroll inside a section that is set with a max-height. With the max-height set, clicking the letter stops working. I assume it is because it is grabbing the window size from the browser and setting the scroll on that somehow, but I really need it do use my section and not the window properties. Is this possible??

I think I have it narrowed down to one line of code:
    $.mobile.silentScroll(1000);
This line seems to scroll the entire page, so if I set the section height property to something and overflow to auto, the above code does not scroll at all.
I think I need something that will scroll inside the element that my data is contained in. On Click, I can change the text of my data just fine with the code below:
    $("#sortedList").text("test text to see if in correct element");
However, I can not find a scrolling event that works with my element that needs it.